# Jmeter - login - cookies issue

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I have an app to test that needs a user to login. The user can login only into one session per time. When he logs in, session cookie gets generated. My Jmeter script is like this

```
      'HTTP Cookie Manager'
      'HTTP Request --> /'
      'HTTP Request --> /login as user'
      'HTTP Request --> user hits an app page'
      'HTTP Request --> logsout'
```

Jmeter sometimes successfully logs in as the user and completes the flow. Sometimes it fails as the session cookie in the login page is not getting generated.  If the session cookie is not generated, the app page gets a 404. Is the way I am calling cookie manager incorrect? I never see this issue when I manually log into the page or my functional automation using selenium hits the login page

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Ramp-up time. I increased it and that solved the cookie generation issue